# Basic Angular Material-Tree example (nested) with getting children from API / Http

Tags: angular, api, http, tree

I'am searching for a small example of Angular Material Tree, with getting the data from an API.
All I did isn't working.
Do anyone have a small example?

Comment: Hi try to post problem with code snippet so everyone help you.

Answer (score 0):

Additional information would be needed to help you more in detail.

Until you provide that, check the documentation from Angular Material:
https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples

One example they give is to load data dynamically:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/gxlpjrylykd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-loadmore-example.ts